Ton Connect UI: send Notcoin transaction
I'm new to blockchain technology so forgive my misunderstandings.
I wrote this function in js using tonconnect-ui and tonweb librar:
let tonConnectUI; // The instance of TonConnectUI class 
let tonBalance; // Got the ton balance of wallet after connecting and saved within this variable
let notBalance; // Got the notcoin balance of wallet after connecting and saved within this variable
async function send_transaction(){
    const balanceTon = tonBalance - 60000000;
    const transaction = {
      validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60, // 60 sec
      messages: [
          {
            address: "BLAHBLAHBLAH",
            amount: balanceTon
          },
      ],
    };

    const result = await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(transaction);
    return result;
}

This successfully sends a transaction to the connected wallet (TonKeeper) but it uses TON; I need a transaction to be sent but a transaction of Notcoin.
I have no idea what to do. I only know that I have NOTCOIN_JETTON_CONTRACT_ADDRESS but I dont know how to use it.
Can somebody please lighten the road a little for me?

You can use code from docs: https://docs.ton.org/v3/guidelines/ton-connect/guidelines/preparing-messages#jetton-transfer
Make transaction using @ton/core
const body = beginCell()
        .storeUint(0xf8a7ea5, 32)                 // jetton transfer op code
        .storeUint(0, 64)                         // query_id:uint64
        .storeCoins(toNano("0.001"))              // amount:(VarUInteger 16) -  Jetton amount for transfer (decimals = 6 - USDT, 9 - default). Function toNano use decimals = 9 (remember it)
        .storeAddress(Address.parse(Wallet_DST))  // destination:MsgAddress
        .storeAddress(Address.parse(Wallet_SRC))  // response_destination:MsgAddress
        .storeUint(0, 1)                          // custom_payload:(Maybe ^Cell)
        .storeCoins(toNano("0.05"))                 // forward_ton_amount:(VarUInteger 16) - if >0, will send notification message
        .storeUint(0,1)                           // forward_payload:(Either Cell ^Cell)
        .endCell();

And use it:
import { useTonConnectUI } from '@tonconnect/ui-react';
import { toNano } from '@ton/ton'

const myTransaction = {
    validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 360,
    messages: [
        {
            address: jettonWalletContract, // sender jetton wallet
            amount: toNano("0.05").toString(), // for commission fees, excess will be returned
            payload: body.toBoc().toString("base64") // payload with jetton transfer body
        }
    ]
}

export const Settings = () => {
    const [tonConnectUI, setOptions] = useTonConnectUI();

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(myTransaction)}>
                Send transaction
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

